# SKAction causes app to crashes on many animation executions with (8-10) images each

Tags: animation, memory-management, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, skaction

- 8-10 large images
- Using SKTexture to load each image using textureWithImageNamed in a for loop
- Put these SKtextures into a NSMutable Array
- Use SKAction to animate textures in the array
- Pressing buttons on-screen makes these animation play
- After 30-40 plays using 9 butons(9 different animations using same code) the app crashes with too many files open

  ```
  for(NSString *frameNumber in animationFrameNumbers)
  {
     NSString *frameName = [NSString
     stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",animationFramePrefix,frameNumber];//filename
     texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:frameName];
     [animationToReturn addObject:texture];  //add texture to NSMutable Array
  }
     SKAction *action=nil;
     action=[SKAction animateWithTextures:animationToReturn
     timePerFrame:animationDelay resize:NO restore:NO];//action with textures
     repeatAction = [SKAction repeatAction:action count:3];//repeat action        
     [animationToReturn removeAllObjects];
     return repeatAction;  //return action to be used
  ```

//another class calls above code

```
       SKAction *action=[animalObject 
       loadPlistForAnimationWithNames:@"polarBearAnim1" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];  //load animation returned into action
       SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"PolarBear1"];
       sprite.position=CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2.5);
       [sprite setZPosition:3];
       [self addChild:sprite];
       [sprite runAction:action]

      [sprite runAction:[SKAction sequence: @[action]] completion:^{
      NSLog(@"Animation complete")
     ;}];
```

Crash log:
2015-07-06 21:24:13.302 Wild Noizes[3066:679465] Error reading plist: DogScene.plist
Jul  6 21:24:13 Erics-iPhone Wild Noizes[3066] : ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B04510BD-B99F-4F93-A791-D486B25712E4/Wild Noizes.app/Dog1_1.png'
             error = 24 (Too many open files)
Jul  6 21:24:13 Erics-iPhone Wild Noizes[3066] : ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B04510BD-B99F-4F93-A791-D486B25712E4/Wild Noizes.app/Dog1_1.png'
             error = 24 (Too many open files)
2015-07-06 21:24:13.325 Wild Noizes[3066:679465] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1859382d8 0x19760c0e4 0x18581ef70 0x18582b200 0x100167c58 0x18a20b770 0x18a223004 0x100157b20 0x18a22092c 0x18a3e488c 0x18a3ddefc 0x18a3b1120 0x18a6522b8 0x18a3af634 0x1858f0240 0x1858ef4e4 0x1858ed594 0x1858192d4 0x18f26f6fc 0x18a416f40 0x1001ccec8 0x197cb6a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: First: you have "texture" set as a variable instead of creating a new instance of texture in the loop. Why? Second: you seem to create an animation sequence, run it and then destroy it again by clearing the array (this is very inefficient). Why?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did have sktexture as a variable in the loop before as well as not clearing the array. But I added these just to see if there was any effect on the crash and there wasn't. So even with your suggestions the app also crashes after around 45-50 animations played. A different animation goes through this code path above each time.

Comment: It would help if you can post the crash log. Also, have you set an All Exceptions break point to see where exactly the crash happens?

Comment: posted the crash log, didn't have any luck with the all exceptions break point.